# Modifying sorting on a facet field from default "count" to "index" in Solrnet asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, solr, solrnet

By default the sort on Solr facet fields is by "count" and not by "index". I have facet fields such as "date", "author", "places" etc. I want the default sort (sort by count/ sort = true) to be applicable only for "author" and "places" facet fields and I want the sort to be changed to sort by "index" (sort = false) for the "date" field. That way, date is sorted in order of the year and author, places are sorted by the count.

I have this piece of code to work with,

```
  Facet = new FacetParameters
                {
                    Queries = AllFacetFields.Except(SelectedFacetFields(parameters))
                          .Select(f => new SolrFacetFieldQuery(f) { MinCount = 1})
                          .Cast<ISolrFacetQuery>()
                          .ToList(),
                },
```

If I include "**Sort = false**" in the **.Select** line above, it affects all the facet fields to change to sort by index. I want to apply "Sort = false" only for facet field "date". How to accomplish that? I am a beginner with linq or solrnet. Please help

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you should split the three facet queries into separate queries where you can control the sort behavior individually.

```
 Facet = new FacetParameters
         {
             Queries = new []
                    {
                       new SolrFacetFieldQuery("author") {MinCount = 1 },
                       new SolrFacetFieldQuery("places") {MinCount = 1 },
                       new SolrFacetFieldQuery("date") {MinCount = 1, Sort = false }
                    }
         }
```

For further information please see the [Facets](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets) page on the [SolrNet Google Code Project Site](https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/).

**Update:** Since there was some additional logic in the original LINQ query, you could do something like the following to achieve a combination of both:

```
      Facet = new FacetParameters
            {
                Queries = AllFacetFields.Except(SelectedFacetFields(parameters))
                      .Select(f => BuildFacetQuery(f))
                      .Cast<ISolrFacetQuery>()
                      .ToList(),
            },


    private SolrFacetFieldQuery BuildFacetQuery(string fieldName)
    {
           var query = new SolrFacetFieldQuery(fieldName) { MinCount = 1 };
           if(string.Compare(fieldName, "date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                query.Sort = false;
           return query;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Paige. But there is a problem with the what you gave. When I click on a facet field value ex. Facet field is "State" and it has values such as "Michigan", "Iowa", "Kentucky" and I click on selecting say "Iowa", now what happens is even after selecting a facet value "Iowa" under "State" facet, I still see "State" facet along with other facet fields and I don't want that to happen. Could you please tell me how I can avoid multiple values?

Comment: Your LINQ statement is essentially filtering out the selected facet items via the `SelectedFacetFields` method and only including the ones that are not selected. You will need to find a new way to both filter the list as well as produce the collection of Facet Queries that knows how to set the sort order for your date field. So you could go back to your original code that you posted and pass fields to another method that can do that. Please see my updated answer.